# python read binary from specific position

Tags: python, file, binary

I have a huge binary file from which I want to read some bytes from exact positions in the file. How can I access specific bytes from binary file not having to loop through all bytes from the beginning of the file?
Thanx,

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure you open the file with the "b" attribute (for example: `file("myfile.bin", "rb")`). Then use the `seek()` method of the file object.

Look here: http://docs.python.org/release/2.4.4/lib/bltin-file-objects.html